# Sharepoint Online REST API - cannot get .aspx files

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, java

I'm using a Java app to get files from sharepoint online.
I'm using the following REST API endpoint:

> apiUrl = BASE_API_URL + "/web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + sharepointList +
>   "')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,EncodedAbsUrl";

I can get the .pdf files that I need that way, but I also have a couple of .aspx files that are simply ignored, like they don't exist.

I'm not sure why that is, and could use some help. Thanks!